# UIScrollView scrolls visibly but NSLog shows it's not

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

This code is for Universal.

I have an iPhone and an iPad layout that are nearly identical. And they are identical as far as object types are concerned.

I'm trying to figure out why my page control doesn't update on just the iPad. After playing around with NSLog it seems that on the iPhone, the `scrollViewDidScroll` method is properly working. It does not on the iPad. No log when touching the scroll view.

I also put in a NSLog to tell me the current page. It does it on the iPad, but only when I call `loadVisiblePages` on my `viewDidLoad` method, not when the scrollView DOES scroll.

*Please ignore the sections where I hard coded the first and last pages as this would normally be done programmatically, but because of this little bug, I've had to load all the pages into memory.*

```
- (void)loadVisiblePages {
    // First, determine which page is currently visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));

    // Update the page control
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    NSLog(@"Page number is %i", page);

    // Work out which pages you want to load
    NSInteger firstPage = 0; // page - 1;
    NSInteger lastPage = 3; //page + 1;


    // Purge anything before the first page
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<firstPage; i++) {
        [self purgePage:i];
    }

    // Load pages in our range
    for (NSInteger i=firstPage; i<=lastPage; i++) {
        [self loadPage:i];
    }

    // Purge anything after the last page
    for (NSInteger i=lastPage+1; i<self.pageImages.count; i++) {
        [self purgePage:i];
    }

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Load the pages that are now on screen
    [self loadVisiblePages];
    NSLog(@"Scroll View Did Scroll");
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that you forgot to connect the scrollview's delegate property in the iPad `xib` to the same object to which you connected it in the iPhone `xib`.

Comment: look at the content size of the scrollview, if it is lower than the view frame size of the ipad, the scrollview wont scroll(as all the content is visible on the screen already)and hence scrollViewDidScroll will never get called. let me know if you still face this issue.. hope this helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the scroll view is scrolling on screen, but not calling the method, it is probably the case that you forgot to set the scroll view's delegate to be the view controller in the iPad storyboard.

Comment: One hundred percent correct sir! No delegate set to the UIViewController! Thank you.